# Finding Regular expression for a string

Tags: php, preg-match

Can anyone help me with finding regular expression for the below

```
$string = "id=A12dk9-mds&name=4950";
```

I need to find regular expression to find a dynamic value (`A12dk9-mds` in this example).

i.e the dynamic content between `=` and `&`

Comment: Will it always be this length and this format?  So 6 letters or numbers hyphen 3 letters?

Comment: hey Daedalus i tried preg_match("/id=*&", $string); , sorry am noob

Comment: why insist on using a regexp when PHP has a parse_str() function to do that job - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex can be used for that.

```
/id=([^&]*)&/
```

**Explanation:**

- `id=` matches id=
- `([^&]*)` matches anything but the & symbol as much as possible and returns that
- `&` matches the &

As long as you know they will always be between a `=` and a `&` this will work.

PHP Code:

```
$string = "id=A12dk9-mds&name=4950";
preg_match('/id=([^&]*)&/',$string, $answer);
print_r($answer[1]);
```

Comment: so it is like preg_match("/=([^&]*)&/", $string);   huh >

Comment: Note: depending on what you are trying to match this could produce false positives in the sense that if you have another place where you have =gibberish& then it will still match that part.  I like my regex patterns to match exactly and only what I am looking for.

Comment: @ajon - True I added id before the equal sign to make sure you will only get the id value.

Comment: Couldn't you also do `/id=(.*?)&/`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yes you could.

Answer (score 2):

As @MarkBaker has stated, the best way to do this is not regex, but [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) since you are actually dealing with a query string of a url.

Therefore, the below should work fine:

```
parse_str($string,$arr);
echo $arr['id']; // A12dk9-mds
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is the wrong tool here.  This looks like a query string, so let's use PHP's query string parser, [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$string = "id=A12dk9-mds&name=4950";
parse_str($string, $parsed);
echo $parsed['id'];
```